Find first element that contain letter 'e' in array
I am solving a question of JavaScript by using find method. I want to find the first and all elements of array that contain letter 'e'.
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'dates', 'fig']

How I solve:
const res = words.find((alpha) => alpha == words)


Where is your code that attempts to solve this problem?

alpha == words makes no sense. words is an array and alpha is one element of this array. I'm not sure if there are some cases, where this returns true, but usually (or always) it returns false and I don't know what you could check with this condition.

How exactly is your attempted solution lacking?

@jabaa It can return true in cases where alpha = words.join(), e.g. ['a'] == 'a'.

@Unmitigated In that case, I prefer if(words.length === 1) res = words[0];.

@jabaa It's also possible to have const arr = []; arr.push(arr);

@Unmitigated That's exactly what I mean. The predicate (alpha) => alpha == words is not directly comprehensible. What would be the use-case? I'm pretty sure, that many developers don't know the exact behavior. Why does the OP compare an element with the whole array?


I want to find the first and all elements

Do you want all the elements or just the first? If you want all, you can use Array.filter. If you want just the first you can use find.


const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'dates', 'fig']
var func = (val) => { return val.indexOf('e') != -1};
let matches = fruits.filter(func);
console.log("all: " + JSON.stringify(matches));

console.log("find: " + fruits.find(func));




You can try this:


    const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'dates', 'fig']
    const result = fruits.filter((alpha) => (alpha.includes('e') || alpha.includes('E')))
    console.log(result)



.filter() will return all the elements that match the condition passed. The original array won't be modified.
.includes() will return true if the string contains the string passed to the function.

You can use Array#filter to get all elements that match a condition and test against the simple regular expression /e/ to check if an element contains the letter "e". It is simple to make this also find upper case letters as well with the ignore case flag: /e/i.


const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'dates', 'fig'];
const res = fruits.filter(fruit => /e/.test(fruit));
console.log(res);




Try this:
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'dates', 'fig']
const results = fruits.filter(el=>el.toLowerCase().includes("e"))
console.log("First Element", results[0])
console.log("All Result", results)

